# Performance considerations for doing simple select on a json format column in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a view with 240 columns in snowflake and we are planning on adding another 70 to the view since we are adding a new feature. I would like to know whats the best approach to be followed in doing so since the view might end up having around more than 100 million rows eventually.

1. Querying snowflake is going to be a simple select, do you think we should have a separate view and do a join with the base view for new feature or maintain the same view with additional columns. Is there any performance gain in not using joins in snowflake.
2. For the new columns we thought of adding just one field to the base view with all columns in json format like a key value pair, If i do a select on json format data is it any less performant than reading from a normal column?

I just wanted guidance on approach to take. The select might have very simple aggregations like count and sum based on WHERE clauses. Which one is best among three

```
1. select ticker, industrycode, sector, assetturnover, esgassetturnover from accounts where ticker is not null and ticker<> '' and industrycode is not null and assetturnover is not null 

2. select ticker, industrycode, sector, assetturnover, esgassetturnover, holding from accounts join pcaf on pcaf.accountid = accounts.accountid where ticker is not null and ticker<> '' and industrycode is not null and assetturnover is not null 

3. select sum(data:premium:companyContributionEsg) as "ESG_CompanyContribution",sum(data:userValue1:companyContribution) as "CompanyContribution", count(data:totalAssets:numberOfAccounts) as "Number of Accounts" from weightedvalues_200 where data:accountId > 200
```

Snowflake has to read from parquet files. so data is going to be written to parquet during import process. There is no nested json if we choose to write in json format.

Answer (score 0):

while Snowflake can query JSON it's generally not a good idea to keep your data as JSON as it has performance implications (and other issues) downstream. Best practice is to hold your data in a proper relational structure whenever possible.

Regarding views, if your view definition was a simple as a "SELECT * FROM TABLE" then there's no issue. As you start making your view definition more complicated (adding joins, calculated columns, aggregation, etc) then there will be a performance hit compared to querying a table.

Only you can determine if the performance hit is acceptable compared with querying a table (that you'll need to keep updated) - based on complexity of views, data volumes, the queries being run, etc